# Diary in Latex with additional notes on side

Tags: environments, margins, boxes, mdframed, sidenotes

I am trying to make a diary that will have the following format

1. Each entry will be inside a colored box
2. Each entry will have a title with the date and an optional title
3. I want the possibility to add notes on the side(preferably at the right one) in a specific line of an entry. The notes will be on a seperate colored box.

I searched the `tex.se` and found two codes to achieve this. The first one comes from Gonzalo Medina's answer on [create a framed environment for a margin note](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120224/create-a-framed-environment-for-a-margin-note)

His way inputs a note on the left side and I believe it would be better if the notes were on right side.

For 1 and 2, I believe that ***ferahfeza*** gave a prety answer on [using latex to keep a diary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68525/using-latex-to-keep-a-diary) however there are some points that are not working because he is probably missing a lot of code.

The idea is to have a `diary.tex`(that contains the definition of a `newenvironment`) file which will be inputed in a main file.

My final output would be a combination of those two

[image]

My code is

**`diary.tex`**

```
\newcounter{diary}
\renewcommand{\thediary}{\arabic{diary}}
\newenvironment{diary}[2]
{\par\medskip\refstepcounter{diary}%
\hbox{%
\fboxsep=\the\sidebar\hspace{-\envborder}\hspace{-.5\sidebar}%
\colorbox{orange}{%
\hspace{\envborder}\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries%
\textcolor{white}{{#1}\ {#2}\enspace\thediary\hspace{\envborder}}
%\today % Print date in header of frame
}}}{\vspace{0.5cm}}
```

The **`main file`** is the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=5cm,textwidth=15cm,marginparwidth=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\reversemarginpar

\newsavebox\mybox
\newlength\BoxHt

\newcommand\caution[2][-2.2\baselineskip]{%
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\parbox{\marginparwidth}{#2}
\end{lrbox}%
\settoheight\BoxHt{\usebox\mybox}%
\raisebox{\BoxHt}[0pt][0pt]{\marginnote{%
  \begin{mdframed}[
    userdefinedwidth=\marginparwidth,
    innerleftmargin=3pt,
    innerrightmargin=3pt,
    linecolor=BrickRed,
    frametitle=\colorbox{white}{\space Caution\space},
    frametitlefont=\color{BrickRed}\sffamily,
    innertopmargin=10pt,
    frametitleaboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlebelowskip=-\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlealignment=\raggedright,
    singleextra={\fill[BrickRed] let \p1=(P), \p2=(O)  in 
    ( $ (P|-0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1) + (0,-4pt) $ ) -- +(4pt,4pt) -- +(0,8pt) -- cycle;}
]\RaggedRight\small#2\end{mdframed}}[#1]}}


\input{diary}


\begin{document}

\begin{diary}{}{14.07.2013}
\lipsum*[3-4]\caution{\lipsum[2]}\lipsum[3-5]
\end{diary}

Some test text\caution{Some text goes here just to illustrate the command}

\lipsum[4-5].\caution{Not forget to do this} This is a line that really needs some caution. But now it's time to move on to the next paragraph. \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

My output is the following

[image]

How to achieve the desired output?

**EDIT**

I tried to achieve the colored background using `mdframed` in a new command, `\note` with 3 arguments. The new `diary.tex` is

```
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrameBlue}{%
    linecolor=blue!20!white,
    outerlinewidth=0pt,
    roundcorner=0pt,
    innertopmargin=-15pt,
    innerbottommargin=-5pt,
    innerrightmargin=0pt,
    innerleftmargin=0pt,
    backgroundcolor=blue!20!white}
\newcounter{diary}
\renewcommand{\thediary}{\arabic{diary}}
\newenvironment{diary}[2]
{\par\medskip\refstepcounter{diary}%
\hbox{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}
\colorbox{orange}{%
\hspace{2pt}\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries%
\textcolor{white}{\thediary. \ {#1}\ {#2}\enspace\hspace{2pt}}
}}}{\vspace{0.5cm}}
\newcommand{\note}[3]{\begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrameBlue]
                          \begin{diary}{#1}{#2}{\vspace{0.5cm} #3}\end{diary}
                      \end{mdframed}
                      }
```

The thing is that when I use `\caution{}` inside the `diary` environment, the background color is adopted.

```
\note{}{14.11.2013}{This is the \caution{Watch the traps!} first note}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh lord. Keeping diary should be a happy thing. You use LaTeX to do it? *[facepalm]*

Comment: @Thanos, I updated my previous answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68525/using-latex-to-keep-a-diary/124504#124504

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: There are also research diaries, high heel princess...

Comment: @ferahfeza: Thank you very much for your comment. The thing is tht I need the box in the side note, as well as the little arrow indicating at which line the note is reffering to. In addition, I think it would be more straight forward not to use the diary entries in a seperate file. Is there a technical reason to do that? Thank's once again for your effort!

Comment: @Thanos: Your welcome. I use separate file because for easy archiving of diaries. It's arbitrary, no technical reason. I'm sorry for boxing, because my time is very limited for writing some documents.

Comment: @ferahfeza: I see! Thank you very much for your time!!! I'll try to see what I can do with the box and the arrow! Thank's once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After ***ferahfeza*** updated his answer on [using latex to keep a diary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68525/using-latex-to-keep-a-diary) the `diary.tex` is updated like that

**`diary.tex`**

```
 \newlength\sidebar
 \newlength\envrule
 \newlength\envborder
 \setlength\sidebar{1.5mm}
 \setlength\envrule{0.4pt}
 \setlength\envborder{2mm}

\makeatletter
 \long\def\fboxs#1{%
   \leavevmode
   \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
     \color@begingroup
       \kern\fboxsep{#1}\kern\fboxsep
     \color@endgroup}%
   \@frames@x\relax}
 \def\frameboxs{%
   \@ifnextchar(%)
     \@framepicbox{\@ifnextchar[\@frameboxs\fboxs}}
 \def\@frameboxs[#1]{%
   \@ifnextchar[%]
     {\@iframeboxs[#1]}%
     {\@iframeboxs[#1][c]}}
 \long\def\@iframeboxs[#1][#2]#3{%
   \leavevmode
   \@begin@tempboxa\hbox{#3}%
     \setlength\@tempdima{#1}%
     \setbox\@tempboxa\hb@xt@\@tempdima
          {\kern\fboxsep\csname bm@#2\endcsname\kern\fboxsep}%
     \@frames@x{\kern-\fboxrule}%
   \@end@tempboxa}
 \def\@frames@x#1{%
   \@tempdima\fboxrule
   \advance\@tempdima\fboxsep
   \advance\@tempdima\dp\@tempboxa
   \hbox{%
     \lower\@tempdima\hbox{%
       \vbox{%
         %\hrule\@height\fboxrule
         \hbox{%
          \vrule\@width\fboxrule
           #1%
           \vbox{%
             \vskip\fboxsep
             \box\@tempboxa
             \vskip\fboxsep}%
           #1%
           }%\vrule\@width\fboxrule}%
         }%\hrule\@height\fboxrule}%
                           }%
         }%
 }
 \def\esefcolorbox#1#{\esecolor@fbox{#1}}
 \def\esecolor@fbox#1#2#3{%
   \color@b@x{\fboxsep\z@\color#1{#2}\fboxs}{\color#1{#3}}}
 \makeatother


 \definecolor{exampleborder}{HTML}{FE642E}
 \definecolor{examplebg}{HTML}{CEF6EC}
 \definecolor{statementborder}{rgb}{.9,0,0}
 \definecolor{statementbg}{rgb}{1,1,1}

 \newenvironment{eseframed}{%
   \def\FrameCommand{\fboxrule=\the\sidebar  \fboxsep=\the\envborder%
   \esefcolorbox{exampleborder}{examplebg}}%
   \MakeFramed{\FrameRestore}}%
  {\endMakeFramed}

\newcounter{diary}
\renewcommand{\thediary}{\arabic{diary}}

 %%% CODE ENVIRONMENT. PUT TEXT INTO COLORED FRAME %%%
 \newenvironment{diary}[2]
 {\par\medskip\refstepcounter{diary}%
 \hbox{%
 \fboxsep=\the\sidebar\hspace{-\envborder}\hspace{-.5\sidebar}%
 \colorbox{exampleborder}{%
 \hspace{\envborder}\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries%
 \textcolor{white}{{#1}\ {#2}\enspace\hspace{\envborder}}
 }
 }
 \nointerlineskip\vspace{-\topsep}%
 \begin{eseframed}\noindent\ignorespaces%
 }
 {\end{eseframed}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\medskip}
```

In the **`main.tex`** ***Gonzalo Medina's*** code will be added, that will give the sidenotes with the pointing arrow, inside a colored box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=5cm,textwidth=15cm,marginparwidth=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\reversemarginpar

\newsavebox\mybox
\newlength\BoxHt

\newcommand\caution[2][-2.2\baselineskip]{%
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\parbox{\marginparwidth}{#2}
\end{lrbox}%
\settoheight\BoxHt{\usebox\mybox}%
\raisebox{\BoxHt}[0pt][0pt]{\marginnote{%
  \begin{mdframed}[
    userdefinedwidth=\marginparwidth,
    innerleftmargin=3pt,
    innerrightmargin=3pt,
    linecolor=BrickRed,
    frametitle=\colorbox{white}{\space Caution\space},
    frametitlefont=\color{BrickRed}\sffamily,
    innertopmargin=10pt,
    frametitleaboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlebelowskip=-\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlealignment=\raggedright,
    singleextra={\fill[BrickRed] let \p1=(P), \p2=(O)  in 
    ( $ (P|-0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1) + (0,-4pt) $ ) -- +(4pt,4pt) -- +(0,8pt) -- cycle;}
]\RaggedRight\small#2\end{mdframed}}[#1]}}


\input{diary}

\begin{document}

\begin{diary}{}{14.07.2013}
\lipsum*[3-4]\caution{\lipsum[2]}\lipsum[3-5]
\end{diary}

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]