# Are there placeholders in LaTeX?

Tags: packages

Are there placeholders in LaTeX of the form:

```
A horse is \placeholder able to fly.

\placeholdertext{not}
```

which should produce an output like:

```
A horse is not able to fly.
```

So I look for an analogon of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` that works with arbitrary content.

I would like to use that for example in combination with `marginpar`, when I want to explain some simple term in a paragraph with a complex `tikz` picture on the side:

```
Some long paragraph in which I mention some term\marginpar{\placeholder} that I want to explain on the side.

\placeholdertext{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Picture for a better understanding of the used term.
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

Another paragraph with some term\marginpar{\placeholder} that I want to explain.

\placeholdertext{
    Some informative text...
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. `\newcommand{\placeholder}{not}` is fine or not?

Comment: Well, that's fine for one occurrence. But what if I would like to use this kind of placeholder repeatedly? Like in the example with `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, I would like to mark the place where I want to add additional contents and then specify these contents after the paragraph.

Comment: @user1742364 your question is not at all clear, the obvious answer as Romain says is that TeX is a macro expansion language (which is another way of saying placeholder) and so \newcommand\placeholder{...} would appear to be the answer. perhaps you could expand the example in the question to show your requirement. (I do not see any connection to footnote currently)

Comment: why do you need the `\placeholder` macro at all it does not seem to be doing anything useful, why not just put the tikzpicture in the marginpar (if you want to define \placeholder you can of course do that but a macro that is only used once for each definition is never really needed.

Comment: @DavidCarliste, you are right that I do not really need it. It is only a matter of good looking and better structured LaTeX-code. It's the same thing with footnotes, I could define them at the place of their marker with `\footnote` but that would somehow destroy the paragraph - I prefer to use `\footnotemark` and later give the contents with `\footnotetext`. Of course I can define a command for each explaination, but then I would need to define dozens of commands that are used only once each, as you said, and the code for the tikzpicture/explaination/... would not be next to the paragraph.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are asking for something more difficult than what you actually want, and confusing a few people in the process :)  Assuming you actually just need this for margin notes, and not as a general purpose thing, you should check out the sidenotes package.  The one problem is that it actually numbers the notes, which you probably don't want.  You can get around this by `\def\thesidenote{}`, but this still leaves a small but visible extra space that I don't know how to get rid of, otherwise I would post this comment as an answer.  But at least now you know where to look :)

Comment: Do you mean something like this ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258437/prevent-overlap-in-margins-by-blocking-some-vertical-space

Comment: Your example is quite different to \footnotemark/\footnotetext: \footnotemark only prints a number, it doesn't have to know the content of the footnote. You seem to want to use a content which is defined later -- this is only possible if you write the content to some auxiliary file and then read it back at the begin of the document - an example where this works is the table of contents: It shows headings which are written later.

Comment: One way to achinve your desire to "mark the place where I want to add additional contents and then specify these contents after the paragraph" is to use `tikzmark` package. Many examples on this site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `todonotes` package to insert not in the margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
A horse is \todo{not} able to fly.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the discussion in the comments, it appears that what is wanted is the ability to define a placeholder *after* it's used.

First, a quick note: The original poster talked about using `\footnotemark` in a paragraph and then `\footnotetext` at the end of the paragraph for the sake of aesthetics in their source code. This is a **bad** idea. For one thing, there is no guarantee that the `\footnotetext` and `\footnotemark` will end up on the same page. For another, the plan breaks down if there is more than one footnote in a paragraph (in that case, the `footnote` counter will need to be manually adjusted so that the footnote texts will have the correct number).

That said, because of the way LaTeX interprets its input, we can't ordinarily define something after it's used.¹ The way around this is to take advantage of the mechanism that LaTeX uses to handle other forward definitions, the `.aux` file.

So we'll want to be able to do something along the lines of:

```
A horse is \PH{horse} able to fly.

\SetPlaceholder{horse}{not}
```

Since I'm doing this off the top of my head,² I'm going to omit niceties like warnings about undefined placeholders or redefined placeholders. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Defining `\PH` is going to be relatively simple. It will just look for a command named `PH@name` for some `name` given and use that for output. I'm going to use some internal LaTeX commands³ here so we'll need to start with

```
\makeatletter
```

and then define `\PH` as:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\PH}{ m }
   {\@nameuse{#1}}
```

A placeholder will be defined by:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefinePlaceHolder}{ m m }
   {\@namedef{#1}{#2}}
```

You might be thinking, wait a minute, weren't we going to define `\SetPlaceHolder`? What's this `\DefinePlaceHolder`?

This is the command that will get written to the `.aux` file to create the placeholder. So we define `\SetPlaceHolder` to be:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetPlaceHolder}{ m m }
   {\@bsphack % ❶
    \protected@write\@auxout{}% ❷
     {\string\DefinePlaceHolder % ❸
        {#1}{#2}}%
    \@esphack % ❶
   }
```

A couple notes here: The sequence `\@bsphack`…`\@esphack` means that `\SetPlaceHolder` won't cause extra spaces to be produced in the output if it appears in the middle of a paragraph.⁴ We use `\protected@write` to write the output to the aux file ❷. This will expand any macros that appear that aren't protected with `\protect` although we can get the same effect with what we're doing by using `\string` ❸ here.

There's still a lot of improvements that can be made to this code. I would recommend doing `texdoc source2e` and jumping down to File F which documents how the cross reference code works. There are some challenges to be had if you want the possibility of an empty placeholder since otherwise `foo \PH{bar} bam` would output two spaces between foo and bam if the placeholder is empty but again, I'll leave all of that as an exercise for the reader.

---

1. This is largely because TeX is essentially a one-pass compilation system. Us older folks who've programmed in 1970s–80s programming languages will be familiar with having to do forward declarations if you want to use a variable or function before it's declared.
2. Which means that all of this code is untested and likely has typos and/or bugs.
3. I was contemplating using Expl3, but a lot of what we want requires other internal commands so I might as well use `\@nameuse` over `\use:c`.
4. This is used by many LaTeX commands that don't produce output and the code involved is rather interesting. Among other things it will make sure that you still get end-of-sentence spacing if you write, e.g., `foo.\label{bar} And more…` The one gotcha is that if you have a command that uses the `sphack` mechanism at the end of a paragraph it can produce a space there that would not otherwise be output which under certain rare circumstances can cause a blank line to appear at the end of a paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are 'placeholders' in (La)TeX -- 'every' macro is a place holder that will be expanded to it's meaning (or is a primitive that does something different)

The `xspace` package is just for the correct spacing after the macro, but some will frown on this.

The question is now: Is it worth to use much of those place holders? Rather not.

In my opinion, it is better use a `glossary`, e.g. `glossaries` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\placeholder}{not\xspace}
\begin{document}

A horse is \placeholder able to fly.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh no a `\xspace` ;-)

Comment: @RomainPicot: I see a conflict with.... you know whom I mean :D

Comment: I added a full example to the original question to clarify what I want to achieve (hopefully :-) )

Comment: @user1742364: That's a fragment and no full example

Answer (score 1):

There's also the `skeldoc` package to insert some blank placeholder space. For example the following code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{skeldoc}
\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\skelline
\Blindtext[1]
\skelpar[4]
\Blindtext[1]
\section{\skelline}
\Blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

would produce the following document:
[image]

More info and examples in the docs: https://github.com/mlhetland/skeldoc.sty