# Tikzset style to disable blur shadow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, shadows

Is there a style with which I can disable a `blur shadow` that was already enabled?  Disabling the `draw` and changing the `fill` can easily be down with appending the options:

```
draw=none, fill=yellow
```

but didn't see an wasy way to disable an exsiting  `blur shadow`.

[image]

### Note:

- One solution would be to define a `\MyPicture*` as per [Temporarily disable Tikz shadow in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354720/4301), but I would prefer to do this using a style, *without* changing `\MyPicture`

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\newcommand*{\MyPicture}[1][]{%
    %% #1 = draw options.
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [draw=red, thick,fill=magenta!25,  blur shadow, #1] {Text};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\MyPicture
\quad
\MyPicture[draw=none, fill=yellow, blur shadow={}]% <-- How to disable shadow here

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change `shadow opacity` parameter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\newcommand*{\MyPicture}[1][]{%
    %% #1 = draw options.
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [draw=red, thick,fill=magenta!25,  blur shadow, #1] {Text};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\MyPicture
\quad
\MyPicture[draw=none, fill=yellow, blur shadow={shadow opacity=0}]% <-- How to disable shadow here

\end{document}
```

[image]