# Cannot set sbox inside tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

(updated version after Qrrbrbirlbel's answer: I want to measure tikz nodes)

I'd like to compute the width of the content (tikz multiline node) that I will typeset in a tikz-cd node to adapt the shape of a parent node. However, sbox created inside tikz have zero width, and typesetting a `tikzpicture` inside it gives me an infinite recursion… any idea why and how to avoid that issue?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\tmpbox}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myNode}{m}{
  \node[inner sep=5pt,fill=green,draw,align=center]{#1};
}

\def\myContentOfInterest{\begin{tikzcd}\myNode{42\\and multiple lines};\end{tikzcd}}
\def\myContentOfInterestTikzVersion{\begin{tikzpicture}\myNode{42\\and multiple lines};\end{tikzpicture}}
Goal: measure the content of \myContentOfInterest

\sbox\tmpbox{\myContentOfInterest}%
\def\myvalue{\the\dimexpr\the\ht\tmpbox\relax}
Outside tikz: \myvalue

Inside tikz:
\tikzset{
  my style/.style={
    /utils/exec={%
      %%%%% works but too simple:
      % \pgfmathheight{"this works but too simple case"}%
      % \edef\myvalue{\pgfmathresult pt}%
      %%%%% fails (infinite computation):
      % \pgfmathheight{"\noexpand\myContentOfInterestTikzVersion"}%%
      % \edef\myvalue{\pgfmathresult pt}%
      %%%%% fails: issue with infinite recursion \pgf@selectfontorig ->\pgf@selectfontorig 
      % \sbox\tmpbox{\myContentOfInterestTikzVersion}%
      \def\myvalue{\text{What should I do to measure the final node itself?}}
    },
  }
}

\begin{tikzcd}[font={\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}]
  \node[my style]{\myvalue};
\end{tikzcd}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The proper font is not set up because TikZ installs the nullfont inside (so that spaces don't mess things up). You might just want to use the PGFMath functions `width`, `depth` and `height` instead and save yourself the hassle. (They do exactly that, they typeset a box with the right font and measure it.) You will need `\selectfont` (for LaTeX) at the start, it seems.

Comment: (You could also put a rectangular node with no inner and outer seps and no drawn border and measure the node with appropriate tools but I believe the PGFMath functions are enough.)

Comment: Why that complicated construction when `\the\ht\tmpbox` suffices? And `\ht\tmpbox` doesn't need `\the` in front of it inside a `\numexpr`, by the way.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks a lot, `\pgfmathheight` gives a nice result… but unfortunately it fails for multiline content (ideally I’d like to measure the width of a tikz node directly). I updated my MWE. Any idea how to make it work here as well?

Comment: @egreg Oh, it comes from simplifying my example to a MWE, I was doing more advanced computation inside. But good to know `\the` is useless, thanks!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel what do you mean by "appropriate tools"? I tried to add a node but I get an infinite recursion.

Comment: 1. See [`discard node` key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694967). Give the node a name and then you can measure all the things with it you need. This will create the node the same as without it and TikZ has the same control over it as usual. (I can't say anything about the box's dimension, don't trust it.) Adding key `overlay` to the node might be advisable. 2. There's also [Deferred Node Positioning](https://tikz.dev/base-nodes#sec-106.2.3). Have never used it, seems powerful, might be even better.

Comment: Well measuring text, measuring text inside a node and measuring a node are three different things. Inside a matrix things work a bit different but we have to see whether they interfere her. (A matrix will correct all nodes' positions after the matrix has been constructed because only then the true location of the matrix is known.)

Comment: Why do you want to measure the height of one node inside another node? (If that's what you're trying to do, which it may very well not be as I'm quite confused.)

Comment: @cfr Because I want to have multi-row/column gates in a tikz matrix, so I need first to measure the final content of the box, compute the width of the inner nodes by basically dividing the width by the number of columns minus column sep, and fit my final node around them. The final result can be seen here, go to section "circuit-related" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leo-colisson/zx-calculus/main/doc/zx-calculus.pdf

Comment: I've got code enabling the measuring of dimensions in the usual way inside a `tikzpicture`. That interrupts the picture environment (see @Qrrbrbirlbel comment below), but it obviously doesn't give the *node*'s dimensions, but only the dimensions of the content, possibly set in a different font or whatever. The code is originally from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56405. (The code I'm using may be modified - I don't remember.) But I'm not sure if that's what you need here?

Comment: @cfr Yeah, its exactly what I was looking for, thanks to you and Qrrbrbirlbel!

Answer (score 1):

My original answer was really dirty, thanks to Qrrbrbirlbel for its great suggestion. The solution was:

```
      \begin{lrbox}{\tmpbox}% <- this create a box (like savebox but environment)
        \begin{pgfinterruptpicture}% <- this resets the font
          \begin{pgfpicture}%
            \node{foo};%
          \end{pgfpicture}%
        \end{pgfinterruptpicture}%
        %\let\selectfont\pgf@selectfontorig%
      \end{lrbox}%
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\tmpbox}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myNode}{m}{
  \node[inner sep=5pt,fill=green,draw,align=center]{#1};
}

\def\myContentOfInterestBasic{\myNode{42\\and multiple lines};}
\def\myContentOfInterest{\begin{tikzcd}\myContentOfInterestBasic\end{tikzcd}}
Goal: measure the content of \myContentOfInterest

\sbox\tmpbox{\myContentOfInterest}%
\def\myvalue{\the\dimexpr\the\ht\tmpbox\relax}
Outside tikz: \myvalue
\rule{\myvalue}{\myvalue}

\makeatletter
Inside tikz:
\tikzset{
  my style/.style={
    /utils/exec={%
      \begin{lrbox}{\tmpbox}
        \begin{pgfinterruptpicture}%
          \begin{pgfpicture}
            \myContentOfInterestBasic%
          \end{pgfpicture}
        \end{pgfinterruptpicture}%
        %\let\selectfont\pgf@selectfontorig%
      \end{lrbox}%
    },
  },
}
\makeatother

% Works:
\begin{tikzcd}
  \node[my style]{\myvalue};
\end{tikzcd}

% Works:
\begin{tikzcd}[font={\fontsize{18}{12}\selectfont}]
  \node{Test};
\end{tikzcd}

%% Works now
\begin{tikzcd}[font={\fontsize{18}{12}\selectfont}]
  \node[my style]{\myvalue};
\end{tikzcd}

\rule{\myvalue}{\myvalue}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The [`pgfinterruptpicture` environment](https://tikz.dev/base-scopes#pgf.pgfinterruptpicture) seems relevant here, I'd even say necessary (even though you don't put the box into the picture later). But this doesn't apply the same settings you get with TikZ (`text width` and `align` and then there's also `text depth` and `text height`). How do you deal with transformation? TeX will report the same dimensions but if the user applied `scale=2` the text will be twice as large in the end.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks! This seemed to be a much cleaner solution indeed… and works nicely EXCEPT than I cannot change anymore the font of the rest of the picture (see MWE below my own answer)… any idea what I got wrong?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Arg, just made a stupid mistake without realizing that I forgot to remove an inner tikzpicture, now it works perfectly, and is much cleaner, thanks a lot! Regarding the transform, do you mean if you scale the whole picture? Hum, not sure what would happen here ^^

Comment: I wouldn't trust a TikZ `\node` inside a `pgfpicture` but maybe it works. I'm still confused what you're trying to measure for what purpose. If you use `my style` as part of a node the `\myvalue` only return the right value inside that node operation since the `\tmpbox` is only locally set. So the last `\rule` uses the value from your first `\sbox\tmpbox{\myContentOfInterest}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Oh really? It does work in my tests, but what should I use as a container instead? I can use a tikzpicture here or it is too high level? For the goal, it is just to create in tikzcd a way to merge columns and rows. The simpler is maybe to look at example, just go to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leo-colisson/zx-calculus/main/doc/zx-calculus.pdf in section and look for the `\zxGateMulti` command. Regarding the last rule, sure, it is just to see how big the text is supposed to be, and in practice I use global variables and more to pass my state to the right state.